# Unable to fetch the images dynamically inside django template

Tags: django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to fetch the images for my template-website but  its not working.
I'm using loop inside html body to save time and space but it's not working.

<--code-->

```
{% for listing in listings%}
        
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
          <div class="card listing-preview">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ listing.photo_main.url }}" alt="" />
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
              <h2>
                <span class="badge badge-secondary text-white">{{ listing.price }}</span>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="listing-heading text-center">
                <h4 class="text-primary">{{ listing.title }}</h4>
                <p>
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker text-secondary"></i> {{ listing.address }}
                </p>
              </div>
              <hr />
```

<-- end of code -->

This is not working:

```
src="{{ listing.photo_main.url }}"
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As reviewed your code. It seems like you haven't ended your for loop `{% endfor %}`

Comment: No, I have ended my for loop. I can't show all the code because of its length.

Comment: Sorry buddy. Can u show the error you are facing.